# android ant build is not working

Tags: android, android-build

I am trying to build my android project with ant as i have to do build process with batch processing.

But 'ant debug' is not working for me. It stops at java code compilation where import packages are not resolved.

I have build same project with eclipse and it works fine.
All jars are in libs folder even thought 'ant' is not able to find libraries.

Below is the terminal output

---

```
AmanMacbook:android tpfmacbookpro1$ ant debug
Buildfile: /Aman/Tegra/workspace_PM/bld_pm_cityskateboarding/android/build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 22.3.0
 [checkenv] Installed at /Aman/Tegra/android-sdk-macosx

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: PZPlayer
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.0.1
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for PZPlayer...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.1.2
[gettarget] API level:        16
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Aman/Tegra/workspace_PM/bld_pm_cityskateboarding/android/bin/rsObj
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Aman/Tegra/workspace_PM/bld_pm_cityskateboarding/android/bin/rsLibs
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for PZPlayer...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...
   [subant] No sub-builds to iterate on

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] No changes in the AndroidManifest files.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] Found 1 AIDL files.
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] No changed resources. R.java and Manifest.java untouched.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] Generating BuildConfig class.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 85 source files to /Aman/Tegra/workspace_PM/bld_pm_cityskateboarding/android/bin/classes
    [javac] /Aman/Tegra/workspace_PM/bld_pm_cityskateboarding/android/src/com/kayabit/AppLovinX/AppLovinXBridge.java:12: package com.applovin does not exist
    [javac] import com.applovin.*;
    [javac] ^
    [javac] /Aman/Tegra/workspace_PM/bld_pm_cityskateboarding/android/src/com/kayabit/PlayHavenX/PlayHavenXBridge.java:9: package com.playhaven does not exist
    [javac] import com.playhaven.*;
    [javac] ^
    [javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac] 2 errors

BUILD FAILED
/Aman/Tegra/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:720: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Aman/Tegra/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:734: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```